# Multiple request are going to ajax if I scroll how to make it one request for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

If I try to call Ajax after by scrolling multiple requests are going for same ajax how to solve this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var element = $('.MainChatList');
    var scrolled = false;
    if (element.scrollTop() + element.innerHeight() >=  element[0].scrollHeight)
    {
        if(!scrolled){
        scrolled = true;
        var scroll = 'scroll';
        loadMain(null, scroll);
        scrolled = false;
        }
     }
});
```

loadMain Ajax()

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'process.php',
    data : { request : "LoadMainView", limit:limit, scroll:scroll }
}).done(function( data ) {
    $(".AdminMainViewLoader").hide();
    if(data)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var html_content = obj.html_content;
        var scr = obj.scroll;
        var data_type = obj.data_type;
        if(scr == 'scroll')
        {
            console.log(scr);
            $(".MainChatList tbody").append(html_content);
        }
        else
            $("#MainView .MainChatData .main-two").html(html_content);
    });
```

Here is ajax request that receiving multiple request

Comment: Without seeing your code it's going to be very hard to help you. Please share it. My best bet is that you make a timer that resets / starts on scroll and when you stop scrolling it will call the ajax

Comment: Please explain your question briefly and add your code here.

Comment: Add flag before calling the end point. BAsed on the flag status you can trigger end point again

Comment: Whenever request for the ajax just use a flag

Comment: `loadMain` Code too please

Comment: `beforeSend` is one ajax event which you can use to set the flag value to true and when you get success or error you can change the flag

Comment: When you set `var scrolled = false;` **before** `if(!scrolled){` you can be sure that this condition is useless because it will always be evaluated to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// taking a flag
isRequested=false;

// Now checking if not requested
if(!isRequested){
    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'process.php',
    data : { request : "LoadMainView", limit:limit, scroll:scroll }
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
      // here we are setting isRequested to true
      isRequested=true;
    }
    }).done(function( data ) {
    $(".AdminMainViewLoader").hide();
    if(data)
    {
        
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var html_content = obj.html_content;
        var scr = obj.scroll;
        var data_type = obj.data_type;
        if(scr == 'scroll')
        {
            console.log(scr);
            $(".MainChatList tbody").append(html_content);
        }
        else
            $("#MainView .MainChatData .main-two").html(html_content);
       // here we are setting isRequested to false
       isRequested=false;
    });
}
```

Comment: same thing you can do for success and error callback